# Typescript ternary operation with assigment

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-operator

```
const fn = (condition: boolean) => condition ? {a: ""} : {b: ""}
```

I have trouble  with understanding why return type of fn is:

```
{
    a: string;
    b?: undefined;
} | {
    b: string;
    a?: undefined;
}
```

but not

```
{
    a: string;
} | {
    b: string;
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwnAvHAFOCATAljXSALjgCMwwAbAUwEMIBKVAPjizwMjgH44BvWiQBEQgL5wSfUsLHAgA

Comment: I just created this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gfc8ms4r/ and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with TypeScript's type inference – in the function `fn`, there is no other context for TS to discount the possibility of either `a` or `b` existing in either of the conditional's scenarios, so it infers this all-encompassing type you show.

Consider:

```js
const obj1 = {a: ""}

const obj2 = {b: ""}

const fn2 = (condition: boolean) => condition ? obj1 : obj2
```

The returned type of `fn2` is what you proposed the type might be for `fn`; this is because TS has inferred the type for the objects beforehand, in isolation.

[Typescript.org/play example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwnAvHAFOCATAljXSALjgCMwwAbAUwEMIBKVAPjizwMjgH44BvWiQBEQgL5wSfUsLHBQkWHDCkAVgEZU-QXBGi5WRcpUAmTVJl750eElNpMkDoQglyVOoxZtH+ZzyWqGiRGxkA)

[Typescript Docs Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference)